# can subclass constructor method override superclass constructor? "java"

Tags: java, overriding, superclass

is it possible for subclass constructor method override the superclass constructor? since i got a question - superclass(Student), subclass(BachelorStudent), it ask me constructor method for BachelorStudent class must over-ride the Student class. is it the question is having error or something wrong? tq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors are never overriden or inherited. In fact, they cannot be called virtually.

However, you can create a constructor in the subclass which calls a constructor in the parent class.

Comment: so i think the question is mean to call the superclass constructor by using super?

Comment: To add to this, it is infact almost always a good idea to call the constructor of the parent class.